# Vert.x Service Proxies from Kotlin with vertx-codegen

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I've written a vertx service interface in Kotlin, for which I am trying to generate service proxies. However, apart from generating the `generated` directory in `src/main`, it does nothing.

`src/main/java/amb85/portfolio/package-info.java`:

```
@ModuleGen(name = "portfolio", groupPackage = "amb85.portfolio")
package amb85.portfolio;

import io.vertx.codegen.annotations.ModuleGen;
```

I then have the following service interface `src/main/kotlin/amb85/portfolio/PortfolioService.kt`:

```
@VertxGen
@ProxyGen
interface PortfolioService {
    companion object {
        val ADDRESS = "service.portfolio"
        val EVENT_ADDRESS = "portfolio"
    }
    fun getPortfolio(resultHandler: (AsyncResult<Portfolio>) -> Unit)
    fun buy(amount: Int, quote: JsonObject, resultHandler: (AsyncResult<Portfolio>) -> Unit)
    fun sell(amount: Int, quote:JsonObject, resultHandler: (AsyncResult<Portfolio>) -> Unit)
    fun evaluate(resultHandler: (AsyncResult<Double>) -> Unit)
}
```

And the relevant configuration from `build.gradle`:

```
task generateProxies(type: JavaCompile, group: "build",
        description: "Generates the Vert.x proxies") { // codegen
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    source += sourceSets.main.kotlin
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.compileOnly
    destinationDir = project.file("${projectDir}/src/main/generated")
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", "io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor",
            "-Acodegen.output=${project.projectDir}/src/main"
    ]
}
```

I then run `./gradlew portfolio:generateProxies`, but nothing beyond the `generated` directory.

Is it possible to use `vertx-codegen` to generate service proxies based on an interface written in Kotlin? If so, what configuration steps am I missing? If not, is there any other way to generate the proxies? Even better, is there a way to do it entirely in Kotlin, avoiding the java generation or using it as an intermediate step?

Comment: try moving `package-info.java` to the folder with Kotlin sources instead of Java

Comment: Just tried that but still no generated sources.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to use vertx service proxies with `kotlin` is to use [kapt](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html) and vertx-codegen `processor` classified dependency.

In your `build.gradle` you should add following:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {

    kapt "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertx_version:processor"
    compileOnly "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertx_version"

    // other deps go here
}
```

Nothing else needed so far.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works as stated without the complicate build config.

Answer (score 1):

Add the service proxy procesor in order to generate the proxy.

```
kapt "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion:processor"
kapt "io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion:processor"
compile "io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion"
```

And if you are going to generate the service with @VertxGen you should use the package-info.java even if you are writing Kotlin:

```
@ModuleGen(name = "example", groupPackage = "com.some")

package com.something;

import io.vertx.codegen.annotations.ModuleGen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define a source set for `generated`. I have a separate Gradle script `gradle/vertx-codegen.gradle` that I include where needed, and that works fine (its only for Java, so you should adapt it a bit):

```
sourceSets {
    generated{
        java.srcDir "${projectDir}/src/generated/java"
    }
}

task generateProxies(type: JavaCompile) {
    group = "build"
    description = "Generate Vert.x service proxies"

    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.compile
    options.compilerArgs = [
        "-proc:only",
        "-processor", "io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor",
        "-AoutputDirectory=${projectDir}/src/main"
    ]
    destinationDir = file("${projectDir}/src/generated/java")
}

compileJava{
    dependsOn generateProxies
    source += sourceSets.generated.java
}

clean {
    delete += sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs
}
```

Hope this helps!